# MS SQL: How union works inside if exists condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone explain how union works inside if exists? My code is below.

```
if exists(select top 1 ShoppingCartNo from tbSupplierLineItem 
where BidSummaryDueDate>CONVERT(date,getdate()) and ShoppingCartNo=@SC
union
select top 1 ShoppingCartNo from Protrac_Archieve.dbo.tbSupplierLineItem 
where BidSummaryDueDate>CONVERT(date,getdate()) and ShoppingCartNo=@SC)
begin
SQL statements
end
```

Comment: It works the same way as without `if exists`

Comment: Basically a different way to write `if exists() or exists() begin; ...` though I would think the `union` should be `union all` to avoid a sort operator (unless that is already optimized away by being inside the `exists()`)

Comment: Why do you think it would work any different in that context?

Answer (score 3):

The `union` will return a row if *either* of the subqueries has a row.  So, the construct is equivalent to:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from tbSupplierLineItem 
            where BidSummaryDueDate > CONVERT(date, getdate()) and
                  ShoppingCartNo = @SC
           ) or
    exists (select 1
             from Protrac_Archieve.dbo.tbSupplierLineItem 
             where BidSummaryDueDate > CONVERT(date, getdate()) and
                   ShoppingCartNo = @SC
           )
   )
begin
    SQL statements
end;
```

Personally, I think this version is clearer.  It should also be easier for the optimizer to optimize (although that is probably not an issue with this query).

Other notes:

- `EXISTS` measures whether any *row* is returned.  The value on the row is immaterial (even if it is `NULL`).  I use `1` because it is easy to type and clearly specifies the intention.
- `UNION` is a bad idea, because it incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  The `TOP 1` does almost entirely mitigate this issue, however.
- The `SELECT TOP` in an `EXISTS` subquery should be unnecessary.  `EXISTS` "stops" at the first row.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same as outside `if exists`.

`if exists` check if the query between the parentheses returns something.
In this case the result would be the union of your two `select` statements.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that both queries that form the union would execute and if ANY records are returned, the EXISTS is true, else it is false.

Answer (score 1):

See.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
 UNION SELECT 2)
 BEGIN
   SELECT 3
 END
```

OUTPUT : 3

Answer (score 0):

It first combines the result sets of two select queries inside if exists statement and then checks for the existence of any record from those queries.